# Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'T'

Tags: swift

Need to wrap the extension for the view controller instantiating inside the dispatch main thread, but got that error, any ideas how to resolve it?

[image]

```
extension UIStoryboard {

    convenience init(name: StoryboardName) {
        self.init(name: name.rawValue, bundle: nil)
    }

    func instantiateVC<T: UIViewController>(identifier: String = T.identifier) -> T {
        // swiftlint:disable force_cast
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let controller = self.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
            controller.removeBackButtonTitle()
            return controller
        }
        // swiftlint:enable force_cast
    }

    func instantiateInitialVC() -> UIViewController {
        return self.instantiateInitialViewController()!
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot return something from a closure which doesn't have a return value. Do you really need the closure? Actually the code doesn't change anything at the visible UI.

Comment: @vadian yes, because there are some issues with threads, otherwise I get a crash

Comment: Add your code as a text please.

Answer (score 2):

`instantiateVC` should not return a value. You need to add a new argument to this function to pass `controller`:

```
func instantiateVC<T: UIViewController>(identifier: String = T.identifier, completion: @escaping (T) -> Void) {
    // swiftlint:disable force_cast
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let controller = self.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
        controller.removeBackButtonTitle()
        completion(controller)
    }
    // swiftlint:enable force_cast
}
```